# INTERNAL: Write rejected

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

In some cases we get a "Write rejected" error on jobs when loading or joining data from BigQuery, even so the same job works fine with different tables of the same size.

I added the detailed error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: INTERNAL: Write rejected (writer id not found) when talking to tcp://localhost:12345 at 
com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn$2.output(NormalParDoFn.java:232) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn$2.output(NormalParDoFn.java:195) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:310) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:478) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.join.CoGroupByKey$ConstructUnionTableFn.processElement(CoGroupByKey.java:185) Caused by: java.io.IOException: INTERNAL: Write rejected (writer id not found) when talking to tcp://localhost:12345 at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ApplianceShuffleWriter.write(Native Method) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.writeChunk(ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.java:71) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.put(ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.java:54) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.add(ShuffleSink.java:227) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.add(ShuffleSink.java:154) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.process(WriteOperation.java:90) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:147) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn$2.output(NormalParDoFn.java:230) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn$2.output(NormalParDoFn.java:195) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:310) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:478) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.join.CoGroupByKey$ConstructUnionTableFn.processElement(CoGroupByKey.java:185) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:171) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:156) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn.processElement(NormalParDoFn.java:262) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:52) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:147) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn$2.output(NormalParDoFn.java:230) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn$2.output(NormalParDoFn.java:195) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:310) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:478) at 
com.dubsmash.analytics.functions.extracts.ExtractSessionFn.processElement(ExtractSessionFn.java:13) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:171) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:156) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn.processElement(NormalParDoFn.java:262) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:52) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:147) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn$2.output(NormalParDoFn.java:230) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn$2.output(NormalParDoFn.java:195) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:310) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:478) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Keys$1.processElement(Keys.java:65) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:171) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:156) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn.processElement(NormalParDoFn.java:262) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:52) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:147) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn$2.output(NormalParDoFn.java:230) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn$2.output(NormalParDoFn.java:195) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:310) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:478) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.CombineValuesFn$ExtractOutputDoFn.processElement(CombineValuesFn.java:223) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:171) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:156) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn.processElement(NormalParDoFn.java:262) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:52) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:147) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn$2.output(NormalParDoFn.java:230) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn$2.output(NormalParDoFn.java:195) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunner.java:310) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunner.java:478) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.CombineValuesFn$MergeAccumulatorsDoFn.processElement(CombineValuesFn.java:201) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(DoFnRunner.java:171) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunner.processElement(DoFnRunner.java:156) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.NormalParDoFn.processElement(NormalParDoFn.java:262) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:52) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:147) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:184) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:121) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:66) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:130) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:95) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:139) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:124) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience we are investigating. The job id can be helpful for troubleshooting if you don't mind sharing it. You can also privately email it to dataflow-feedback@google.com.

Comment: I cannot access older jobs (more than 1 day old) through console without the error "The Job diagram could not be retrieved from the server.", so it's hard to find the job id, because I would need to write a Java App for that :/

Comment: I found a way, I will send you an email.

Answer (score 1):

This exception should be a transient, non-fatal error. Your job should continue to execute and complete successfully.

Please let us know if your job doesn't complete successfully.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I'm seeing several instances of just this exception in my logs before a dataflow job failed. The job ID is `2017-01-25_19_23_50-689458918219404223`. Is this just a one-off failure?

Comment: This may be a one-off failure. If it occurs frequently you may want to use more workers as this may occur if the workers become overloaded. It could also be an indicator that too much of your data is on the same key.